# How do I set custom navigation bar(title + titleView) for all navigation controllers and view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a tabbed application with navigation controllers in tabs and view controller in them. All of them use the same navigation controller navigation bar: back button + logo image. Currently, I'm placing this code in every view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.navigationItem.title = @"Back";
  UIImage *headerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"];
  self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:headerImage] autorelease];
}
```

IMHO it's not the best way to do that. I'm thinking about using a category for UIViewController and to override viewDidLoad method, but every view controller has some additional code to execute in viewDidLoad, so I guess overriding is not the solution. What are the other ways?

Comment: Do you target iOS 5? In iOS you can set these values globally (e.g. in your appDelegate).

Comment: Currently, nop :) But please let me know how to do that in iOS 5...

Comment: Take a look at UIAppearance: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html I wrote a little example as an answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create a subclass of `UIViewController`, `MyViewControllerWithBackButtonAndLogo` (you can come up with a better name) then implement `viewDidLoad` to set up the navigation item. Make all your view controllers inherit from this base class. Then just make sure the view controllers call `[super viewDidLoad]` in their own implementations.

Also note that to set the back button title, you should not change the navigation item's `title` property, but set an appropriate `backBarButtonItem`.

Comment: This is a really smart answer - I wish I'd thought of it, haha!  Overall I'd say this is just workaround, but not a hacky one at all.  What I'd love to do, personally, is to be able to associate these kinds of customizations with a particular navigation controller, so that all views in its stack would have your additions.  I feel like that should fall within the nav controller's responsibilities, but I might not understand that class too well yet...  Anyway, thanks for this!

Comment: Is it possible to implement the same viewDidLoad method in subclass both for UITableViewController and UIViewController? So, all controllers (views and tables) will have the same nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

In proper architecture a UIViewController (or sub class) should not care in which context it is displayed (e.g. within a UINavigationController, UITabController, modal or not). Consider using the [coordinator pattern](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/71/how-to-use-the-coordinator-pattern-in-ios-apps) where it's the coordinator's responsibility to perform this kind of configuration.

Example:

```
class FlowCoordinator {
    ...

    // The coordinator knows about the navigation controller
    // Individual view controllers do not.
    private let navigationController: UINavigationController

    func presentViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {
        // This setup can be common for all view controllers in this flow
        viewController.navigationItem.titleView = ...
        viewController.backBarButtonItem = ...
        viewController.navigationItem.title = ...
        navigationController.pushViewController(viewController)
    }

    ...
}
```