# Setting a UINavigationItem.titleView = MyLogoView for all UINavigationViewController children UIViews

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

My question is technically a duplicate of this SO: [How do I set custom navigation bar(title + titleView) for all navigation controllers and view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846502/how-do-i-set-custom-navigation-bartitle-titleview-for-all-navigation-control)

The base class answer in the link above is my current solution as I will explain below. One problem with this solution though is that it makes my company logo image titleView disappear and reappear for a second with every segue, I am looking to keep the logo visible through all navigation transitions.

I am using a company logo in the center of my `UINavigationBar`. Currently, for any child UIView of my `UINavigationViewController`, I add a `UINavigationItem` outlet in the Xcode 7 Storyboard by CTRL Dragging to my Swift `ChildViewController` and always use the same ID:

```
@IBOutlet weak var uiNavItemTitle: UINavigationItem!
```

I then delete that above Xcode generated line because I have the same line in `MyBaseViewController` that `ChildViewController` inherits from. Now I can set the logo one time in `MyBaseViewController` and every `ChildViewController` inherits from `MyBaseViewController`, this code is in `MyBaseViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var uiNavItemTitle: UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // MARK: - UINavigationController Defaults
    uiNavItemTitle.titleView = CoreUtility.LogoForUINavBarGet()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "";
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

}
```

What is becoming an issue with this solution is that for every ChildViewController in my UINavigationViewController stack of segues, I have to add a `UINavigationItem` outlet and make sure I inherit `MyBaseViewController`. Some of my navigation segue views deeper in the navigation chain should not really inherit from this `MyBaseViewController` though.

**Another issue with my solution is that the company logo disappears and reappears a second later for each segue to a new UIViewController**

I can create another level to the hierarchy of inheritance is one possible solution.

But my UINavigationItem.titleView is always the same company logo for every child UIViewController segued to.

Do I have to add a UINavigationItem to every UIViewController?

Or is there an "Application" level way such as using, in my `AppDeletgate.application()`:

```
//MARK: - UINavigationBar.appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UINavigationBar.somethingForTitleView
```

Where `somethingForTitleView` becomes code to set a Application wide Navigation Bar titleView to my logo View.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846502/how-do-i-set-custom-navigation-bartitle-titleview-for-all-navigation-control

Comment: Yes it does seem like a duplicate, though I am looking for a different solution than I currently have and the duplicate SO you provided recommends the same base class solution I currently have. I also added to my question that my logo disappears and reappears for every segue with the base class solution, I would like to fix this, if possible